Android 14: Overlay Button Service (TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY) glitches to previous position on first click
Code Updated[28-11-2024]
Issue Description:
When the overlay bubble is dragged from position A to position B and then clicked for the first time at position B, it briefly glitches/teleports back to position A before returning to position B. This only happens on the first click after moving to a new position.
Environment:

Android Studio Ladybug | 2024.2.1 Patch 2
Compose Version: "2024.04.01
Tested on:
Android 14 (where the issue occurs)
Android 13 and below (works correctly)

Relevant Code:
class FloatingBubbleService : Service() {
    private lateinit var windowManager: WindowManager
    private var bubbleView: ComposeView? = null
    
    // Track last known good position
    private var lastKnownX = 0
    private var lastKnownY = 0

    private val viewOwner = object : LifecycleOwner, SavedStateRegistryOwner {
        val lifecycleRegistry = LifecycleRegistry(this)
        private val savedStateRegistryController = SavedStateRegistryController.create(this).apply {
            // Initialize the SavedStateRegistry immediately
            performRestore(Bundle())
        }
        init {
            lifecycleRegistry.currentState = Lifecycle.State.CREATED
        }

        override val lifecycle: Lifecycle
            get() =  lifecycleRegistry

        override val savedStateRegistry: SavedStateRegistry
            get() = savedStateRegistryController.savedStateRegistry
    }

    private val params = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE or 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN or 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
    ).apply {
        gravity = Gravity.TOP or Gravity.START
        x = 0
        y = 0
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? = null

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        windowManager = getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
        setupFloatingBubble()
        viewOwner.lifecycleRegistry.currentState = Lifecycle.State.RESUMED

    }

    private fun setupFloatingBubble() {
        bubbleView = ComposeView(this).apply {
            setViewTreeLifecycleOwner(viewOwner)
            setViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner(viewOwner)
            
            var initialX = 0
            var initialY = 0
            var initialTouchX = 0f
            var initialTouchY = 0f
            var isDragging = false

            setContent {
                var isMenuVisible by remember{ mutableStateOf(false)}
                FloatingBubbleTheme {
                    FloatingBubbleContent(
                        isMenuVisible = isMenuVisible,
                        onBubbleClick = { /* Not needed anymore */ },
                        interceptTouchEvents = false
                    )
                }
                setOnTouchListener { view, event ->
                    Log.i(LOGTAG, "Touch event received: ${event.action}")
                    when (event.action) {
                        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                            Log.i(LOGTAG, "ACTION_DOWN++")
                            isDragging = false
                            initialX = params.x
                            initialY = params.y
                            initialTouchX = event.rawX
                            initialTouchY = event.rawY
                            true
                        }

                        MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                            if (!isDragging && (Math.abs(event.rawX - initialTouchX) > 10 ||
                                Math.abs(event.rawY - initialTouchY) > 10)) {
                                isDragging = true
                            }

                            if (isDragging) {
                                val newX = initialX + (event.rawX - initialTouchX).toInt()
                                val newY = initialY + (event.rawY - initialTouchY).toInt()
                                Log.i(LOGTAG, "Moving to ${newX}: ${newY}")
                                params.x = newX
                                params.y = newY

                                try {
                                    windowManager.updateViewLayout(view, params)
                                } catch (e: Exception) {
                                    e.printStackTrace()
                                }
                            }
                            true
                        }

                        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                            if (!isDragging) {
                                // Toggle menu visibility using mutable state
                                isMenuVisible = !isMenuVisible
                            }
                            true
                        }
                        else -> false
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        try {
            windowManager.addView(bubbleView, params)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        bubbleView?.let { windowManager.removeView(it) }
        viewOwner.lifecycleRegistry.currentState = Lifecycle.State.DESTROYED

    }
}

Expected Behavior:
The overlay bubble should stay at position B when clicked, without any position glitch.
Actual Behavior on Android 14:

Drag overlay bubble from position A to B
Click bubble at position B
Bubble briefly glitches back to position A
Bubble returns to position B

What I've Tried:

Different WindowManager.LayoutParams flags combinations
Checking for position updates in onDraw
Verifying touch coordinates and window parameters

Question:
Is this a known issue with Android 14's WindowManager? Are there any workarounds to prevent this position glitch when clicking the overlay view?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!
UPDATED[26/11/2024]
@Composable
fun FloatingBubbleContent(
    isMenuVisible: Boolean,
    onBubbleClick: () -> Unit,
    interceptTouchEvents: Boolean = false
) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(174.dp)  // Fixed width
            .height(56.dp)  // Fixed height
            .then(
                if (interceptTouchEvents) {
                    Modifier.clickable(onClick = onBubbleClick)
                } else {
                    Modifier
                }
            )
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(56.dp)  // Fixed bubble size
                .align(Alignment.CenterEnd)  // Align bubble to the right
        ) {
            BubbleIcon()
        }
        
        AnimatedMenu(
            isVisible = isMenuVisible,
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterStart)
        )
    }
}

@Composable
private fun AnimatedMenu(
    isVisible: Boolean,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = isVisible,
        enter = fadeIn() + slideIn(initialOffset = { IntOffset(-50, 0) }),
        exit = fadeOut() + slideOut(targetOffset = { IntOffset(-50, 0) }),
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(118.dp)  // 70dp + 48dp
                .height(56.dp)  // Match bubble height
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .offset(x = (-70).dp),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
            ) {
                MenuButton(
                    icon = Icons.Rounded.Call,
                    backgroundColor = Color(0xFF4CAF50),
                    onClick = { /* Handle call */ }
                )

                MenuButton(
                    icon = Icons.Rounded.Email,
                    backgroundColor = Color(0xFF2196F3),
                    onClick = { /* Handle email */ }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

UPDATED[28/11/2024]
Manifest file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.FloatableIcon"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name="com.example.floatableicon.service.FloatingBubbleService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />
    </application>

</manifest>


Width and height of the view may be changing in FloatingBubbleContent when you change isMenuVisible = true.

@TomBerghuis Yes the width and height of the view are changing but I don't see why that may be causing an issue
For your reference I have added the code for FloatingBubbleContent

If you could also add where your viewOwner is coming from and which permissions you have in your manifest.xml, it would make testing your code much easier.

@BenjyTec I have  updated the code

I could not reproduce the issue on the emulator API34. Can you replace your FloatingBubbleContent by simply using FloatingBubbleTheme { Box(modifier = Modifier.size(60.dp).background(Color.Red)) } and report back if the issue still occurs?

Did you add some animation on the overlay button click?
Issue still occurs after the checking with the changes suggested by you
